# Click a button to show, elsewhere to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I looked at similar questions here but non of them really got me anywhere.

So my setup is something like this :

```
<body>
  ...some code
  <button id="button" onClick="showPopup()">click me!</button> 
  <div id="popup">
    ...stuff
  </div>

  ..some more code

</body>
```

for my css I have

```
#popup{
  z-index:2;
  ...other styling
}
```

while everything else is z-index 1

and javascript

```
$("#popup").hide();   //default
function showPopup(){
   $("#popup").show();
}
```

I want the popup to show when the button is clicked, and hide when anywhere else is clicked.

```
$(document).click(function (e){$("#popup").hide();}
```

This won't work because popup is part of the document so when the button is clicked, it shows then hides immediately.
I also tried adding class and hiding if hasClass but didn't work.
Also the fact that z-index is different has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the inline event handler and do

```
$("#popup").hide();

$(document).on('click', function(e) {

    if ( $(e.target).closest('#button, #popup').length ) {
        $('#popup').show();
    } else if ( $('#popup').is(':visible') ) {
        $('#popup').hide();
    }

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0v09p4dn/)

Answer (score 1):

Add one more handler on popup to stop event bubbling, so click event won't reach document if occurred within popup. Also don't use inline `onclick` handler since you have jQuery for more unobtrusive approach:

```
$('#popup').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $("#popup").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e){
    $("#popup").hide();
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $("#popup").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e){
    $("#popup").hide();
});

$('#popup').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#popup{
  z-index:2;
  display: none;
  background: #EEE; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click me!</button>
<div id="popup">...stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write it more in your javascript and leave the `onClick=` out of it.  That's just my personal preference.

Here's how I would approach it:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    $('#popup').show();
});
$(document).not('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('#popup').hide();
});
```

If you're making this act like a modal, I would suggest making your `#popup` fixed position on the screen and 100% width and height, then add a container inside of popup that you can style to look like whatever modal you want.  Then, when you click on `#popup` cover, it will hide it.

Answer (score 0):

All valid answers and makes sense but none of them worked for me. Seemed like

```
$(document).click(function (e){
    $("#popup").hide();
    alert("test");
});
```

never works, doesn't hide or alert me. I think it's something to do with the environment I am working in (Phonegap application)

I ended up adding a button that you click to close it.